# Two dimensional array with different row length. I need to drop min, max and calculate the average for each line in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Average {
static int[][] myDouble = new int[10][12];
static int x = 0, y = 0;
static int strDouble;

public Average() {
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("StudentIdAverage.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values = line.split("\\s+");

            for (String str : values) {
                strDouble = Integer.parseInt(str);
                myDouble[x][y] = strDouble;
                y = y + 1;
            }
            x = x + 1;
            y = 0;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Average arr = new Average();
    //int[][] residuescores = arr.myDouble;
    for (int i = 0; i < myDouble.length; ++i) {
         int sum = 0;
         int average = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < myDouble[i].length; ++j) {
            Arrays.sort(myDouble[i]);
            sum+=myDouble[i][j];
            System.out.print(Average.myDouble[i][j] + " ");
        }
        average = (sum/myDouble[i].length);

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(average);
    }

}
}
```

**input File:-**

> 45 72 90 50 67 63 81 71 55 56 80 74/n 55 54 79 72 75 68/n 51 88 79
>   72/n 98 52 52 53 50 92 67 99 92 50 61 91/n 94 48 53 92 97/n 97 69 77
>   74 68 54 87 74 54 83 58 69/n 75 49 87 61 66 53 79 48 96 60/n 58 71 51
>   73 53 75 93 81 45 69 78 65/n 50 88 78 81 99 61 97 70 87 80 69/n 91 89
>   97 80 93 82 92 49 52 69 96 61

Comment: So what problem are you facing?  BTW, do not silently swallow exceptions `catch (IOException ioException) {
    }`

Comment: The problem is that it prints extra zeros because it is two dimensional array with different row length.  So when I calculate the average it is not correct. plus i need to drop min and max to calculate the average.

Comment: As you only seem to outputting the average line-by-line why use a 2D array, just process as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using java 8 you can utilize streams and SummaryStatistics to calculate average/min/max like below

```
static Integer[][] myDouble = new Integer[10][12];

for (int i = 0; i < myDouble.length; ++i) {
     IntSummaryStatistics statistics = Arrays.asList(myDouble[i]).stream().filter(intValue -> intValue!=null).collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue));
     System.out.println("Average: "+statistics.getAverage()+", min: "+statistics.getMin()+", max: "+statistics.getMax());
}
```

If you can not use java 8 then note that the issue with your code is that you are using primitive int in your array which will initialize the values to 0 and thus you get 0 when the row has less values than 12. One way to solve it is to change your array to Integer class but remember to skip the entries which have null as now instead of 0 you will get null in the rows with less entries.

your code working with int array changed to Integer, skipping nulls and using count instead of array.length:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < myDouble.length; ++i) {
    int count = 0; // count the values used to calculate sum
     int sum = 0;
     int average = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < myDouble[i].length; ++j) {
        if(myDouble[i][j] == null) //skip the null values
            continue;
        //Arrays.sort(myDouble[i]);
        sum+=myDouble[i][j];
        count++;
        System.out.print(App.myDouble[i][j] + " ");
    }
    average = (sum/count); //use count instead of lenght

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(average);
}
```